# How can I insert a sublime-text snippet from the menu or using a key-binding

Tags: sublime-text-3

Is it possible to insert a snippet in sublime text 3 from the menu or some other way?

I read several instructions and many of them said I should define a tab trigger binding with tab, but is it also possible to insert a snippet in another way? I am not using tab triggers.

A key binding with ctrl or alt would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

**Insert a snippet using the menu**

menu `tools > snippets` ...

A lists with all the available snippets appears

**Assign a keyboard shortcut to a snippet**

Find out the relative path to the snippet file inside the sublime data directory. For example: packages/user/mysnippet.sublime-snippet

Go to menu `preferences > keybindings user`

insert this entry into the list. In this example the new keybinding would be `ctrl-7`:

```
{
   "keys": ["ctrl+7"],
   "command": "insert_snippet",
   "args": {
     "name": "packages/user/mysnippet.sublime-snippet"
   } 
},
```

The "command" needs always to be "insert_snippet".

Use forward slashes in the "name", even on windows.

You can use the following modifiers and also glue them together like `ctrl+alt+7`. Some of them try to be platform independendent:

`ctrl`

`control`

`alt`

`option` - apple/pretzl/clover key on a Mac

`command` - command key on a Mac

`super` - the logo key on any keyboard (apple, pretzl, clover, windows, ...)

`primary` - Ctrl on Windows and Linux, or apple/pretzl/clover key on a Mac

You can use `a`-`z` and `0`-`9` and also special keys:

`,` `.` `\` `/` `;` `'` `+` `-` `=` `[` `]` `up` `down` `left` `right` `insert` `home` `end` `pageup` `pagedown` `backspace` `delete` `tab` `enter` `pause` `escape` `spacekeypad0` `keypad1` `keypad2` `keypad3` `keypad4` `keypad5` `keypad6` `keypad7` `keypad8` `keypad9` `keypad_period` `keypad_divide` `keypad_multiply` `keypad_minus` `keypad_plus` `keypad_enter` `clear` `f1` `f2` `f3`, etc

Be sure you don't overwrite a keybinding that you still want. See menu `preferences > keybindings default` and also `preferences > keybindings user` (the file that you are just editing).

I found that most `ctrl+alt` combinations with a letter `a`-`z` (except `p` which is occupied) seem to be unused currently.